# jQuery grab param from url then do stuff

Tags: jquery, mobile, modernizr

I am in over my head with a script I'm trying to get to work.  I have a site where you can click a link for "full site" from the mobile version to strip off the mobile styles and load all the slides in a slideshow.  The link is just "?mobile=off" for whatever page you're on.  So I'm writing a script to grab that param from the URL and then have an if else statement.  Here's what I have and its not working.  It always goes to the else part of the statement even when the correct conditions are met, so I don't think its getting the param value in the if statement. It does work if I just use if (Modernizr.mq'(max-width: 1000px)')) without the urlParams in that if statement.

```
var urlParams;
(window.onpopstate = function () {
    var match,
        pl     = /\+/g,  // Regex for replacing addition symbol with a space
        search = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g,
        decode = function (s) { return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(pl, " ")); },
        query  = window.location.search.substring(1);

    urlParams = {};
    while (match = search.exec(query))
       urlParams[decode(match[1])] = decode(match[2]);
})();


if ( (Modernizr.mq('(max-width: 1000px)')) && (urlParams[mobile] == ('undefined')) ) { 
        //this stuff removes all except first slide in flexslider for mobile
        $(".flexslider li:not(.keep)").remove();
        $( ".flexslider" ).removeClass( "flexslider loading" ).addClass( "noslider" );
        $( ".slides" ).removeClass( "slides" ).addClass( "noslides" );

} else {
      //strips off mobile stylesheet and loads all flexslider slides
      $("#mobile").remove();
      $(window).load(function(){
      $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "fade",
    animationSpeed: 3500,
    directionNav: false,
    controlNav: false,
    smoothHeight: false,
    slideshow: false,
    useCss: false,
        start: function(slider){
          $('body').removeClass('loading');
        }
      });
    });

$('.prev, .next').on('click', function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $('.flexslider').flexslider(href)
    return false;
});
}
```

Comment: Console.log() and browser developer tools are your friends

Comment: Couldn't you just trigger an event when the button is clicked instead of using params?

Comment: @JBaczuk - I looked in the javascript console in Chrome, but its not showing any errors :(

Comment: @JacqueGoupil - I don't think I can go that route because the page has to be reloaded to get the full slideshow back because the extras slides were removed not just hidden.

Comment: @Amy Did you try to print what you're getting from the url to the console?

Comment: @JBaczuk - if I put in alert(urlParams["mobile"]); I get "undefined" when its not set and I get "off" when its set to off, so I know that's getting picked up, I think the if statement isn't formatted correctly, but I don't know why.

Comment: @JBaczuk - I just tried with the console and I get 'undefined' and 'off' there too depending on the url

Comment: @AmyBillMckenzie I think you're checking for undefined incorrectly, try my answer and see what happens.

Comment: I fixed it - removed the quotes are "undefined" and it works -

Comment: Great! Mark an answer, or create your own if it's different so it's easy for people to see the exact code that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your if statement to:

```
if ( (Modernizr.mq('(max-width: 1000px)')) && (urlParams[mobile] === undefined) ) {
```

You could also do:

```
if ( (Modernizr.mq('(max-width: 1000px)')) && (typeof(urlParams[mobile]) == 'undefined') ) {
```

Comment: both of these also work - also, just removing the quotes around the word "undefined" in my original expression